# How to use jquery autocomplete combobox with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am very new to jquery-ui. I want to use [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) with ajax. (ASP.NET MVC 5) I created jquery-ui-combobox.js and added inside jquery(combobox) functions.

I want to use like this. Is this argument(source) correct ?

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#combobox").combobox({source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetProjects",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        /*I dont know what I should here*/
                         })
                        );
                    }
                });});
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
            $("#combobox").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller :

```
        public JsonResult GetProjects(string term)
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "ActionScript" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "AppleScript" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Asp" });
        var res = list.Where(p => p.Text.Contains(term));
        return Json(res , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


                                                                                                Please help.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Success You can do like this...

```
 $("#combobox").append("<option value=''>Select</option>");
                    $.each(data, function (value, key) {
                        $("#combobox").append("<option value='"+key.Value+"'>"+key.Text +"</option>");
                    });
```

Comment: Ok. I added; thank you @Raghava Nalkari . But $.Ajax not triggered.